# Правильно ли, что всякое слово в коде на c# является либо оператором, либо переменной, либо литералом?

Tags: c#, операторы

Собственно, вся суть вопроса в заголовке.

Comment: что здесь имеется ввиду под "словом"?

Comment: кроме оператора есть еще операнд.

Comment: @Bulson, операнд может быть и переменной и литералом :) все сходится

Comment: @Grundy, ну да 

Comment: а также имя пользовательского типа и другие ключевые слова, вроде модификаторов доступа, которые не относятся ни к чему из перечисленного или компоненты составных операторов вроде switch-case или try-catch-finaly которые имеют смысл только в сочетании. Так что в общем случает ответ - нет. Есть ключевые слова, есть пользовательские имена, есть литералы, есть служебные символы.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду под словом, но в любом случае это неполный список.

Лексика C# описана в спецификации ([Lexical analysis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#lexical-analysis)):

> Five basic elements make up the lexical structure of a C# source file: line terminators, white space, comments, tokens, and pre-processing directives. ...
>
> *Лексическая структура кода на C# состоит из пяти базовых элементов: символы переноса строки, пробелы, комментарии, лексемы и директивы препроцессора.* ...

Про лексемы расписано подробнее ([Tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#tokens)):

> There are several kinds of tokens: identifiers, keywords, literals, operators, and punctuators. ...
>
> *Есть несколько видов лексем: идентификаторы, ключевые слова, литералы, операторы и знаки пунктуации.*

Из этого можно составить список элементов в C#:

- переносы строк, пробелы;
- комментарии;
- директивы препроцессора;
- лексемы:

  - идентификаторы (наименования переменных, классов, методов, полей, свойств);
  - ключевые слова;
  - литералы;
  - операторы (`+`, `-`, `==`, ...);
  - знаки пунктуации (`;`, `{`, `)`, ...)

**UPDATE:** Вопросы в комментариях:

> Большое спасибо за ответы.Теперь, когда я подробней ознакомился с документацией и вашими ответами, правильней было бы сформулировать вопрос так: По какому принципу разные группы операторов в c# объединены в категорию "операторы". Т.е. почему protected - это модификатор доступа( не оператор) а ++ sizeof, а главное while - Это уже операторы? Я думал, что объединение происходит на основании того, что операторы вычисляются в выражениях, и их используют с операндами. Но тогда в это определение не попадает break, continue, while и т.д. – Иван Нимцович 8 часов назад

В комментариях к вопросу у Вас спрашивали, что Вы имеете ввиду под «словом». Это не праздный вопрос. У языка есть [лексика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) (грубо, разбор на составные части) и [синтаксис](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) (грубо, осмысление этих частей). В зависимости от целей «слово» можно понимать по разному.

С точки зрения лексики существуют среди прочего [ключевые слова](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#keywords) (sizeof, while, private) и [операторы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#operators-and-punctuators).

С точки зрения синтаксиса есть [выражения](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-as-operator), в которые входят операторы (`+`, `as`, `sizeof`), [инструкции](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements) (часть выражений, while, switch), классы, структуры, интерфейсы и перечисления (с модификаторами доступа разных уровней), пространства имен.

Т.о. понятия «ключевое слово» и «инструкция цикла» существуют на разных уровнях. Инструкция состоит из ключевых слов и выражений.

> Т.е. почему protected и другие ключевые слова - не называют оператором "модификатор доступа"

[Операторами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)) как правило называют конструкции, которые используются в выражениях, принимают и возвращают значения. К модификаторам доступа это плохо подходит.

Немного сложнее ситуация с `sizeof`. Понятие оператор задано в спецификации несколько раз. С точки зрения лексики, это набор знаков, которые используются в выражениях (`+`, `-`, `&&`). С точки зрения синтаксиса это еще и специальные встроенные функции (`is`, `as`, `sizeof`, `nameof`). Т.о. `sizeof` можно назвать оператором, но говорить что язык состоит из ключевых слов и операторов, среди которых `sizeof` не совсем правильно. На уровне лексики `sizeof` — ключевое слово, на уровне синтаксиса — оператор.

Еще сложняет ситуацию, что по-русски довольно часто операторами называют инструкции (*statement*). В учебной литературе можно встретить «условные операторы» и «операторы цикла». Так что технически Вы можете назвать `while` оператором, но следует иметь ввиду, что такое название не связано со спецификацией языка.

Comment: Всё-таки identifiers надо переводить как "идентификаторы". Это давно уже русское слово, которое прекрасно подходит по смыслу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Согласен. Исправил.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы.Теперь, когда я подробней ознакомился с документацией и вашими ответами, правильней было бы сформулировать вопрос так: По какому принципу разные группы операторов в c# объединены в категорию "операторы". Т.е. почему protected - это модификатор доступа( не оператор) а ++ sizeof, а главное while - Это уже операторы?
Я думал, что объединение происходит на основании того, что операторы вычисляются в выражениях, и их используют с операндами. Но тогда в это определение не попадает break, continue, while и т.д.

Comment: Т.е. почему protected и другие  ключевые слова - не называют оператором "модификатор доступа"

Comment: @ИванНимцович Обновил ответ.